# Java 8 map streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there a way to make this code use Java 8?

```
public static boolean areBooleansValid(Map<String, Object> pairs, List<String> errors, String... values) {
    for (String value : values) {
        if (pairs.get(value) == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (!(pairs.get(value) instanceof Boolean)) {
            errors.add(value + " does not contain a valid boolean value");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Was thinking something like this:

```
Stream<Object> e = Stream.of(values).map(pairs::get);
```

but how can I get it to return the different boolean values from this stream?

Comment: Given the fact that you are populating `errors` in addition to getting this boolean value, I would advise you not to do this.

Comment: On a side note: you could try to reuse the result of `pairs.get(value)` inside the loop so that you only need to call it once. On another side note: I'd add the error message outside the method, i.e. `if( !areBooleansValid(...) ) { errors.add(...); }`. Currently your method/function is doing too much. Separating both should make converting the actual logic to streams quite easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to filter out the values that are Boolean and present in the `pairs` map, you can apply filter function:

```
Stream.of(values).filter(value ->  pairs.get(value) != null && pairs.get(value) instanceof Boolean)
```

Or if you want to actually return `true` and `false` values, you can use map:

```
return Stream.of(values).allMatch(value -> {
            if (pairs.get(value) == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if ((pairs.get(value) instanceof Boolean)) {
                return true;
            }
            errors.add(value + " does not contain a valid boolean value");
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: @maloney, if you want error aggregation, the Java8 approach looks very similar to what you already have.

Comment: curlyBraces this doesn't seem to ever enter the block of code after value ->

Comment: @maloney, I have modified the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need Just :

```
return Arrays.stream(values)
       .allMatch(value -> pairs.get(value) instanceof Boolean);
```

---

Notes

- I don't see any reason of `error` in your method
- also as [@Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53006355/java-8-map-streams/53006440?noredirect=1#comment92916747_53006440) mention in comment `pairs.get(value) instanceof Boolean` implies `pairs.get(value) != null` so you don't need to use `pairs.get(value) != null`

Comment: errors is needed to return a message to the user. If it goes into first if statement -> don't tell user, second if statement -> do tell user

Comment: @maloney in Java you can return just one argument not two, so can you please explain how you want to use this method so I can gives you another idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can reproduce exactly the same behavior as your original code using

```
public static boolean areBooleansValid(Map<String, Object> pairs,
                                       List<String> errors, String... values) {
    Optional<String> opt = Arrays.stream(values)
        .filter(s -> !(pairs.get(s) instanceof Boolean))
        .findFirst();
    opt .filter(s -> pairs.get(s) != null)
        .ifPresent(value -> errors.add(value+" does not contain a valid boolean value"));
    return !opt.isPresent();
}
```

Just like your original code, it just searches for the first item that is not a `Boolean` (might be `null`), but adds an error only if the value is not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Object> errors = Stream.of(values)
        .filter(value -> value == null || !(pairs.get(value) instanceof Boolean))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> errorMsg = errors.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(value -> "" + pairs.get(value) + " does not contain a valid boolean value")
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    errors.addAll(errorMsg);
return errors.isEmpty();
```

Comment: I'd suggest you add a few words explaining what you did and why. Also note that your application would probably result in a `ConcurrentModificationException` (or similar) due to it effectively being `errors.forEach( errors.add(...))`. Additionally if there are more than one errors you'd have generate the same message multiple times.